# Updating an array of objects without mutation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have an object:

```
[
   {
       "value":"d1",
       "label":"bathstore.com",
       "selected":true
   },                             
   {
       "value":"d2",
       "label":"superdrug.com",
       "selected":true
   },
   {
       "value":"d3",
       "label":"papajohns.com",
       "selected":true
   }
]
```

how can I change every value of 'selected' field to 'false' using spread operator or Object.assign() to avoid object mutation?

Comment: Are you saying you want a new array of new objects with those properties updated?  If not, what do you mean by _" to avoid object mutation"_?

Comment: You can use Object.assign to create a new object with the updated properties of the old one

Comment: `I want to update the original array without mutating it` huh? How is that not a contradiction?

Comment: @Fran data = data.map((item) => {
    return {...item, selected: false};
 }); should do it

Comment: @KananFarzali That's not updating the original array, that's creating an entirely new one.  If any other variables other than `data` point to the old array, they'll still have the old data.  The end result might work for you, but it's really not clear what you're asking to achieve in the question and comments here.

Comment: @KananFarzali I know the solution but that's not updating the original as it creates a new one. I'm confused by the mix-up in your use of the buzzwords.

Comment: so it is fine. Create a copy and update it. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can iterate over array with `map` and inside each callback use spread syntax to create new objects with updated property:

```js
let data = [
   {
       "value":"d1",
       "label":"bathstore.com",
       "selected":true
   },                             
   {
       "value":"d2",
       "label":"superdrug.com",
       "selected":true
   },
   {
       "value":"d3",
       "label":"papajohns.com",
       "selected":true
   }
];
 let newData = data.map((item) => {
    return {...item, selected: false};
 });
 console.log(newData);
```